# javascript calling wrong spring post method

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a javascript code that makes a post request when a link is pressed,

```
$(document).on("click", "#name", function () {
    try{

     var userid= $(this).data('id');


     var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
      form.setAttribute('action', '/biz/getadmindsr');  

         var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                 hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                 hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "userid");
                 hiddenField.setAttribute("value", userid);

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);


        document.body.appendChild(form);

        form.submit();
    }
    catch(err)
    {

        alert('Inside excpetion'+err.message);
    }
});
```

However the spring controller it is invoking is as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get_admindsr_employeelist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getdsr_page(ModelMap model)
```

The expected controller is as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getadmindsr", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getdsr(ModelMap model,@RequestParam("userid") String userid)
```

When I make a request via postman the second controller gets invoked correctly, but when called through a javascript snippet it invokes the first controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential reason can be that the link clicked is followed, before the form is created and submitted.

You should prevent that by replacing:

`$(document).on("click", "#name", function () {`

with:

`$(document).on("click", "#name", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...`

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. The problem was the same as you said.